# Virtual destructor of base class is not called when downcasting is done via dynamic cast

Tags: c++, casting, downcast

When I run the following code, I get the following issue. 
Deleting derived pointer d1 does not call the destructor of the base class. Deleting derived pointer d2 calls the base destructor. Why is the type of cast (dynamic or static) affecting whether base destructor is called or not.

```
class Base  
{ 
  public :  

  Base() { std::cout<<"Base Ctr"<<std::endl; }  

  virtual ~Base() { std::cout<<"Base Dtr"<<std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base  
{ 
  public :  
  Derived() { std::cout<<"Derived Ctr"<<std::endl; }  

  ~Derived() { std::cout<<"Derived Dtr"<<std::endl; }
};

int main()
{  
  Derived* d1 = static_cast<Derived*>(new Base());

  delete d1;

  Derived* d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(new Base());

  delete d2;
}
```

Output:

```
Base Ctr
Base Dtr
Base Ctr
```

Note : I have not displayed the virtual functions in base class ( because of which base destructor was made virtual in the first place) for simplicity.

Comment: Please post some compilable code.

Comment: do you mean adding header fiiles @juanchopanza ?

Comment: @PranavKapoor: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Also your question is broken because the output of this program, even when "fixed", is _not_ as you claim.

Comment: Yes, but more importantly, change `class` for `struct` to make things `public`.

Comment: the first one was a static_cast, i'm new to posting questions(in fact, this was my 1st one) , please cut me some slack.

Comment: Now you changed the nature of the question and invalidated all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dynamic_cast` fails in both cases, as you cannot safely downcast a `Base` to a `Derived` (your initial object is a `Base`, `new Base`). You should test the result of the dynamic cast

```
if(!d1) // d1 is nullptr here
    std::cout << "Failed dynamic_cast";
```

Delete-ing a `nullptr` is a no-op, so no destructor is called.

Answer (score 1):

This cast fails and returns a `nullptr`:

```
Derived* d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(new Base());
```

The reason is that the object isn't of type `Derived`. You then call `delete` on `d2`, which is a no-op:

```
delete d2; // deleting nullptr => no-op
```

So, you leak the object behind `d2`.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the type of cast (dynamic or static) affecting whether base destructor is called or not.

It's not, but deleting a null pointer does not invoke any destructor. You have a null pointer because you tried to `dynamic_cast` a `Base` to `Derived`, which will obviously fail.

In fact, this will be the case for *both* pointers, so the output in your question is from some other code that you did not show. Naughty!

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
  Base* d1 = new Derived();
  delete d1;
```

Or even better:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> d1 = std::make_unique<Derived>();
```

Or

```
Derived d1;
Base *b = &d1;
```

Comment: My question relates to downcasting. Your answer relates to upcasting.